# Is there a Prisma way to run specific code inside a subscriber/hook like "after delete" or something like that?

Tags: postgresql, orm, nestjs, prisma

I have a parent board that has many lists, each list has many tasks, each task can have many attachments, so it goes like this Board -> List -> Task -> Attachment.

Each attachment/file data (the attachment itself) is stored in an Object Storage server (MinIO for my case, could be S3 or whatever).
Every time I delete a single attachment or all attachments I also clear my bucket in parallel as well, and for now I only run that MinIO deletion when I delete attachments from the task, e.g.
`DELETE /task/:taskId/attachment` (delete all attachments under a task), or `DELETE /attachment/:attachmentId` (delete a specific attachment).

If I delete the list itself that is full of tasks, or even delete the board itself... it means that I need to perform that MinIO operation in all of those contexts, which is really bad, I don't wanna keep track of every delete operation that would require to clear the bucket.

Is there any Prisma-way to do this in a way that works like a subscriber or some kind of pubsub thing? TypeORM and MikroORM that treats tables as entities (and that repository pattern stuff) has a built-in subscribers that you can use to hook up with every operation like update or insert or delete of any kind of entity with metadata...

I read the Prisma docs, they offer [middlewares](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware) but they're now deprecated as of the time I am writing this, and they offer another API called [extensions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions/query), and nothing of these actually focus on this specific issue, they can help you to log what happened, or extend a built-in API like `findMany` or `create`, and this is not what I am looking for. Also there is this [$on](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#on) function and that also I am not sure it's suited for what I am looking for as it seems to be useful for logging (just displaying things) and not for performing some operations.

What I need is a way for me to run my minio code to clear the bucket with a given file name every time a file gets removed either by a direct request on the file resource or any of its parents.

I'm using Prisma 5.* (5.5.2) and Postgres. And I am also using Nest.js and this is not a specific issue for Nest.js I guess, I just want to figure out how to deal with automatic repetitive operation in a good Prisma way.

I tried looking for the docs and many GitHub issues, nothing found that could lead to something.

P.S. I am thinking of extending the Prisma client and extending `delete` function for all modals, but I need a way to retrieve the file metadata somehow, and a subscriber like how TypeORM works would actually helps because it runs every time a resource will be manipluated either directly using an HTTP request or from any of its parents that would affect it.

Help is really appreciated!